# Are you able to have sheets with the same name but in different workbooks in excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is that I have a template file (Monthly Report)  with 455 lines and a DataDownload file where the number of lines varies. When there is no data for a region and a segment it is left out. In all other respects the two files are the same. i.e. Sheet names are the same. My code below is just overwriting the information in the template from the DataDownload.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyanpaste()
Dim linecount As Long
Dim linecount2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim region As String
Dim region2 As String
Dim segment As String
Dim segment2 As String
Dim i As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("3 REGION SEGMENT")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("3 REGION SEGMENT")
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("DataDownload")
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks("Monthly Report - 201705")
linecount = 4
linecount2 = 4
For i = 1 To 455
With wb
With ws
region = ws.Cells(linecount, "B")
segment = ws.Cells(linecount, "D")
End With
End With
With wb2
With ws2

region2 = ws2.Cells(linecount2, "B")
segment2 = ws2.Cells(linecount2, "D")
End With
End With
If region = region2 And segment = segment2 Then
wb.Sheets("3 REGION SEGMENT").Cells(linecount2, "A").EntireRow.Copy   Destination:=wb2.Sheets("3 REGION SEGMENT").Range("A" & linecount)
linecount = linecount + 1
linecount2 = linecount2 + 1
Else
linecount2 = linecount2 + 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is, the title isn't really reflected in the body.  However, yes you can. Just make sure to include the workbook before the sheet in all instances. You did this with `wb.Sheets("3 Region Segment").Cells(...`, but not earlier where you `set ws = Worksheets("3 REGION SEGMENT")`. What workbook is that in?

Comment: @BruceWayne Worksheets("3 REGION SEGMENT") is the same in both workbooks "DataDownload" and "Monthly Report - 201705". What do I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to shift some code around so that you define each workbook first and then use those workbook objects to define the worksheets within each.

```
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("DataDownload")
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks("Monthly Report - 201705")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("3 REGION SEGMENT")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("3 REGION SEGMENT")
```

Additionally, you are not using the With ... End With blocks correctly. This,

```
With wb
With ws
region = ws.Cells(linecount, "B")
segment = ws.Cells(linecount, "D")
End With
End With
```

... should be,

```
With ws
    region = .Cells(linecount, "B")
    segment = .Cells(linecount, "D")
End With
```

You do not need the `With wb` at all since you defined (as above) ws to be a worksheet within wb. Further, a With ws ... End With block defines the parent worksheet of cells so ws.cells is redundant; just .cells will do.

Indenting your code properly will go a long way towards finding these small errors easily.